# How do I link to tabbed section and open the tab content?

Tags: javascript, tabs, onclick

I'm trying to modify my Woocommerce product page, such that I have a hyperlinked text under the pricing that will move down the page to a tab in the section and will additionally open that tab.

I have entered the hyperlinked text with php in the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'write_a_review_link', 10 );
function write_a_review_link() {
  echo '<a href="#x-legacy-tab-2" class="write-a-review">Share Your Experience With These Shoes</a><br>';
}
```

It appears on the product page like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHw7f.png)

It links upon clicking to this section, but I would like it to open the tab in blue upon clicking: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACWNb.png)

From what I can gather, it requires creating a function in javascript, but I'm not experienced with javascript. Any guidance here on making this happen?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! [This tutorial](https://jonathanbossenger.com/using-anchor-links-to-open-accordions-and-tabs-in-divi/) was exactly what I needed to figure it out.

Here's the jQuery I added to my site:

```
jQuery(function ($) {


var open_accordion_anchor = $('#open-tab-discussions a');
open_accordion_anchor.on('click', function(event){
    $('#product-page-tabs .wpc_comment_tab_tab a').click();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#product-page-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);
});

});
```

`#open-tab-discussions` is the id that I assigned to the hyperlinked text to click up top.

`#product-page-tabs` is the ID that I assigned to the tabs div.

`.wpc_comment_tab_tab` is the class of the tab I’m interested in opening.

The href in the clickable link was changed to a # instead of the ID of the tab like I had in my original php.

I hope this can help someone else!